# Is there a difference between $g(x): x \mapsto f(x)$ and $g(x):=f(x)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, transformation

Assume that $f$, $f_1$, and $f_2$ are arbitrary functions.

I have looked at several different scenarios to see if $g: x \mapsto f(x)$ would ever be syntactically preferable, to no avail:

$$
g: x \mapsto f(x) \quad\equiv\quad g(x):=f(x)
\\
g: x,y \mapsto f(x,y) \quad\equiv\quad g(x,y):=f(x,y)
\\
g: \begin{cases} x \mapsto f_1(x) \\ y \mapsto f_2(y) \end{cases} \mid x \in X \land y \in Y \quad\equiv\quad g(x):=\begin{cases} f_1(x) & x \in X \\ f_2(x) & x \in Y \end{cases}
\\
g: \begin{cases} X \to Z \\ x \mapsto f(x) \end{cases} \quad\equiv\quad g(x):=f(x) \mid x \in X \land f(x) \in Z
$$

None of these cases make the first option seem preferable... not even the last one, considering that $X$ and $Z$ must be predefined for it to not be ugly:

$$
g: \begin{cases} \left\{n \mid n \in \Bbb Z \land n \gt 10\right\} \to \left\{f(n) \mid n \in \Bbb Z \land n \gt 10\right\} \\ x \mapsto 2x+1 \end{cases}
\quad\equiv\quad \\
g: \begin{cases} X \to Y \\ x \mapsto 2x+1 \end{cases} \mid X,Y := \left\{ n, f(n) \mid n \in \Bbb Z \land n \gt 10 \right\}
\quad\equiv\quad \\
g(x):=2x+1 \mid x \in \Bbb Z \land x > 10
$$

So it doesn't make sense to me why the first option even exists.

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject#Definition_symbols), says that...

- $A:B$ should be interpreted as "$A$ is defined by $B$"
- $A:=B$ should be interpreted as "$A$ is defined as equal to $B$"

But I don't see any functional difference between the two. Am I missing something?

---

Edit: here's a much simpler explanation of my question. I don't understand why the parallel between $\to$ and $\mapsto$ is so flawed:

- Given a function $f : a \mapsto b$...

  - Domain: $x = a$
  - Codomain: $y = b$
  - Range: $f(x) = f(a)$
- Given a function $f : A \to B$...

  - Domain: $X = \left\{ a \mid a \in A \right\}$
  - Codomain: $Y = \left\{ b \mid b \in B \right\}$
  - Range: $f[X] = \left\{ f(x) \mid x \in X \right\} = f[A] = \left\{ f(a) \mid a \in A \right\}$

Comment: What if you don't want to give the function a name?  I can talk about $x\mapsto x^2$ without having to bother naming it.

Comment: @saulspatz I suppose that makes sense... but how would you be able to call such a function then? I'm sure there are some cases where you wouldn't have to, but I can't think of any.

Comment: What do you mean by "call it"?  Are you talking about a computer program, or do you mean how would I refer to it?  If the latter, I could just say, "the function $x\mapsto x^2$" or "$x$ goes to $x^2$."  If the former, many language have facilities for literal functions, often called "lambdas."

Comment: @saulspatz I just don't understand how it could be used in any formal mathematical notation. To explain what I mean, consider an arbitrary function $f$ again. $g: X \to Y$ allows you to refer later to the function $g$, the domain $X$, the codomain $Y$, and the range $f[X]$. $g: X \to f[X]$ gives you function $g$, codomain $f[X]$, and range $g[X]$. On the other hand, $g: x \mapsto f(x)$  means the same as $g(x):=f(x)$ and $g: x \mapsto y$ doesn't really mean anything AFAIK.

Comment: I appended a better explanation of what I mean to the end of the original post.

Comment: [Anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) are often used in function arguments. For example, define $f:g\mapsto(x\mapsto g(g(x)))$ and then write $f(x\mapsto\sin(x))=\sin(\sin(x))$. Of course, such writing is usually simply for the sake of convenience.

Comment: Another example of when it may be cumbersome to write it with $g(x)=f(x)$ is if you want to refer to $g$ as it's own stand-alone object. It is, imo, clearer to write $g:x\mapsto x^2$, and then write something such as $g\circ g\ne\text{id}$, opposed to writing $g(x)=x^2$ and $g(g(x))\ne x$, since the latter is not actually true for $x=0,1$. Or, perhaps, when [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) a function, it is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt if you put that down below as an answer I'll mark it correct and +1; this is pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ported from comments:

[Anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) are often used in function arguments, especially computer science. For example, define $f:g\mapsto(x\mapsto g(g(x)))$ and then write $f(x\mapsto\sin(x))(x)=\sin(\sin(x))$. Of course, such writing is usually simply for the sake of convenience.

Another example of when it may be cumbersome to write it with $g(x)=f(x)$ is if you want to refer to $g$ as it's own stand-alone object. It is, imo, clearer to write $g:x\mapsto x^2$, and then write something such as $g\circ g\ne\operatorname{id}$, opposed to writing $g(x)=x^2$ and $g(g(x))\ne x$, since the latter is not actually true for $x=0,1$. Or, perhaps, when [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) a function, it is a bit cleaner.

In programming the latter case occurs more often than one may think at first. Many languages support functions, which are defined somewhat like $g(x)=f(x)$, but then it is impossible to reference $g$ alone. The alternative is usually called a lambda function or similar. You can find many programming examples of when these are preferable to use just by asking Google.

Comment: Quick follow-up: would $f(\sin)(x)$ also equal $\sin(\sin(x))$?

Comment: Also, what is "id"?

Comment: $id$ is the identity function. And about your first question, your notation is weird. What would mean $f(\sin(x)))(x)$? Do you mean $f(\sin(x))?

Comment: @CélioAugusto Well I mean, you said in your post that $f(x \mapsto \sin(x))(x) = \sin(\sin(x))$. I get that $g: x \mapsto x^2+1$ isn't the same as simply $x^2+1$ because you can say $g(2)=5$ but you can't say $(x^2+1)(2)=5$ as it's a syntactical nightmare. Therefore, you can say $f(x \mapsto x^2+1)(x)$ but you can't say $f(x^2+1)(x)$ because it's equally ambiguous. But in the case of $h: x \mapsto \sin(x)$, both $h(\frac \pi 2)$ and $\sin(\frac \pi 2)$ make sense, so couldn't you say either $f(x \mapsto \sin(x))(x)$ or $f(sin)(x)$?

Comment: @CélioAugusto $f$ isn't defined on numbers. It takes functions as inputs. Something such as $f(\sin(1))$ doesn't make any sense, but $f(\sin)$ does. If $g=f(\sin)$, then $g$ is a function with $g(x)=\sin(\sin(x))$.

Comment: @QuaternionsRock yes in that case you could say $f(\sin)$, though you can't say something like $f(x^2+1)$.